# Azure: CLI OData filter string matching

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, odata

How to filter results using the OData filter on matching substrings?

```
$ az ad app list --help
...
Arguments:
    --filter                        : OData filter, e.g. --filter "displayname eq 'test' and
                                      servicePrincipalType eq 'Application'".
```

As per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http#operators-and-functions-supported-in-filter-expressions), I should be doable using for example `contains` function. I'm getting:

```
$ az ad app list --filter "contains(displayname, 'some-name')"                                                                                        
An unknown function with name 'contains' was found. This may also be a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are getting this error but when I ran the following command:

```
az ad app list --filter "contains(displayname, 'some-name')"
```

I got the following error:

```
Unsupported property filter clause operator 'Contains'.
```

which makes sense considering you cannot use `contains` function with `displayName` property. Functions supported for `displayName` property are: `eq`, `ne`, `not`, `ge`, `le`, `in`, `startsWith`, and `eq` on `null` values.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties.

Comment: Tried using newer client version, the error I got was the same. Thank you for referencing the docs explaining the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `az rest` with `$search` could help. The following command returns the applications when display name contains word `demo`:

```
az rest --method get --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$search="displayname:demo"' --headers ConsistencyLevel=Eventual
```

Comment: If you don't mind a client-side filtering, you can also do:
az ad app list --query "[?contains(displayName, 'Demo')]" -o table

Comment: The `az rest` doesn't work as it returns also App Registrations others than the ones containing a `demo` string in their `displayname` values.

I'd prefer to use server-side filtering, as I'm executing this in a large enterprise environment (5K App Registrations and growing).

Comment: Have you executed `az rest` command in Bash or PowerShell?

Comment: I'm running it in Bash